# Python3. How to optimize decorator for handling exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, optimization, python-decorators

I have decorator that I use as exceptions handler. I want to optimize it, because comparing with simple try...catch it is about 6 times slower.

The code of my decorator:

```
class ProcessException(object):

    __slots__ = ('func', 'custom_handlers', 'exclude')

    def __init__(self, custom_handlers=None):
        self.func = None
        self.custom_handlers: dict = custom_handlers
        self.exclude = [QueueEmpty, QueueFull, TimeoutError]

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        return self.wrapper

    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.custom_handlers:
            if isinstance(self.custom_handlers, property):
                self.custom_handlers = self.custom_handlers.__get__(self, self.__class__)

        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(self.func):
            return self._coroutine_exception_handler(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self._sync_exception_handler(*args, **kwargs)

    async def _coroutine_exception_handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if self.custom_handlers and e.__class__ in self.custom_handlers:
                return self.custom_handlers[e.__class__]()

            if e.__class__ not in self.exclude:
                raise e

    def _sync_exception_handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if self.custom_handlers and e.__class__ in self.custom_handlers:
                return self.custom_handlers[e.__class__]()

            if e.__class__ not in self.exclude:
                raise e
```

As benchmark I used simple function with try...catch and function with my decorator:

```
# simple function
def divide(a, b):
    try:
        return a // b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 'error'

# function with decorator
@ProcessException({ZeroDivisionError: lambda: 'err'})
def divide2(a, b):
    return a // b
```

Result for 10000 iterations of simple function:

```
timeit.timeit('divide(1, 0)', number=10000, setup='from __main__ import divide')
0.010692662000110431
```

And function with decorator:

```
timeit.timeit('divide2(1, 0)', number=10000, setup='from __main__ import divide2')
0.053688491000002614
```

Help me please to optimize it and please explain where is bottleneck ?

Comment: From my profiling it seems that most of the slowdown is from `if self.custom_handlers and e.__class__ in self.custom_handlers:`. If you're really looking for efficiency, writing a decorator may not be the way to go.

Comment: @rassar thanks for the comment. Do you mean decorator always will be slower? Can you please clarify what is the best way to create exceptions handler?

Comment: Hm. Simply by having more lines, the decorator must jump through more hoops and therefore take longer. Additionally, since you want to be able to specify the exceptions and functions, it will take longer to parse these and process these. It's unlikely that you'll be able to find a faster or better implementation than what you have presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I have optimized my decorator. So, the code (explanation below):

```
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction

from asyncio import QueueEmpty, QueueFull
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError


class ProcessException(object):

    __slots__ = ('func', 'handlers')

    def __init__(self, custom_handlers=None):
        self.func = None

        if isinstance(custom_handlers, property):
            custom_handlers = custom_handlers.__get__(self, self.__class__)

        def raise_exception(e: Exception):
            raise e

        exclude = {
            QueueEmpty: lambda e: None,
            QueueFull: lambda e: None,
            TimeoutError: lambda e: None
        }

        self.handlers = {
            **exclude,
            **(custom_handlers or {}),
            Exception: raise_exception
        }

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func

        if iscoroutinefunction(self.func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self._coroutine_exception_handler(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self._sync_exception_handler(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    async def _coroutine_exception_handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            return self.handlers.get(e.__class__, Exception)(e)

    def _sync_exception_handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            return self.handlers.get(e.__class__, Exception)(e)
```

First, I used cProfile to see what calls was made by decorator. I noticed that asyncio.iscoroutinefunction make extra call. I've removed it. Also I removed all extra `if` and created common dict for all handlers. My solution still not fast as just try...catch, but now it works more faster.